# Fortranの改行出力について

Tags: fortran

簡単なコードなのですが、上手くいかない部分がありましたので投稿しました。

下記の②が正解で、常に左端だけに8を出力して、
それに続くように0～119まで120個が8列毎に改行して出力するものです。

③が作成したコード結果ですが、最初だけ8が出て改行されますが、
その後、8が追加されず最後まで行ってしまいます。

①のコードで次の部分に問題があると思います。

```
write(10,"(9i5)") N8, (Nd(i4),i4=1, NDOF)
```

もし修正法が分かりましたら教えて頂きたく存じます。

#### ソースコード等

①777.f90

```
i1=0

do i3=1, NDOF

Nd(i3)=i1

i1=i1+1

end do


N8=8

write(10,"(9i5)") N8, (Nd(i4),i4=1, NDOF)
```

②

```
8 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
8 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
8 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
8 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
8 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
8 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
8 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
8 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71
8 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
8 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87
8 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95
8 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103
8 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111
8 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119
```

③

```
8 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61
62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88
89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97
98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106
107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115
116 117 118 119
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

左端に表示したい`8`をデータではなく書式に含めれば望みの結果になります。

```
      write(ss, '(i5)') N8   ! N8を文字列に変換
      s = '("'//ss//'",8i5)' ! 書式文字列を編集
      write(10,s) (Nd(i4),i4=1, NDOF)
```

動作確認に使用したコード

```
      program sample
      integer Nd(120)
      character (32) s ! 書式文字列
      character (5) ss ! N8の文字列
      NDOF = 120
      i1=0
      do i3=1, NDOF
        Nd(i3)=i1
        i1=i1+1
      end do
      N8=8
      write(ss, '(i5)') N8   ! N8を文字列に変換
      s = '("'//ss//'",8i5)' ! 書式文字列を編集
      write(10,s) (Nd(i4),i4=1, NDOF)
      stop
      end program sample
```

実行結果

```
    8    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
    8    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
    8   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
    8   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31
    8   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39
    8   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47
    8   48   49   50   51   52   53   54   55
    8   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63
    8   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71
    8   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79
    8   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87
    8   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95
    8   96   97   98   99  100  101  102  103
    8  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111
    8  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119
```

動作確認に使用したFortran
`GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0`

Comment: gfortranでコンパイルしてみましたがエラーが出ました。

試しに以下のように修正したところ、問題が解決出来ました。

      do i4=1, NDOF,8

      write(10,"(9i5)")  N8, Nd(i4),Nd(i4+1),Nd(i4+2),Nd(i4+3),Nd(i4+4),Nd(i4+5),Nd(i4+6),Nd(i4+7)

      end do

Comment: ともあれ解決してよかったです。こちらの環境ではコンパイルエラーが出ていません。動作確認に使用したコードを回答に追記しました。よろしければご確認ください。

Comment: コンパイルエラーが解決しました。動作確認も正常でした。文字として扱うアドバイスが有益で参考になりました。

Comment: @shiro うまくいって良かったです。よろしければ回答の承認をお願いします。承認していただければうれしいです。回答の左側にあるチェックマークをチェックすると承認ができます。

Comment: 早速チェックマークをチェックしました。初めて実施しましたので正しく反映されているか不安です。

Comment: @shiro 承認されていました。ありがとうございます。承認されると質問が未解決の一覧から外れます。